# ASP.NET Core 2 Url Rewriting middleware to redirect from .xxx to .yyy extension

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, rewriting

I want to redirect all request from .com to .net with the same path and route in dot net core.

Same as below code for removing www from start URL:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(ctx =>
{
    // checking if the hostName has www. at the beginning
    var req = ctx.HttpContext.Request;
    var hostName = req.Host;
    if (hostName.ToString().StartsWith("www."))
    {
        // Strip off www.
        var newHostName = hostName.ToString().Substring(4);

        // Creating new url
        var newUrl = new StringBuilder()
                              .Append(req.Scheme)
                              .Append(newHostName)
                              .Append(req.PathBase)
                              .Append(req.Path)
                              .Append(req.QueryString)
                              .ToString();

        // Modify Http Response
        var response = ctx.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = newUrl;
        response.StatusCode = 301;
        ctx.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your existing code to change the com to net.

```
if (hostName.ToString().EndsWith(".com"))
{
    // change the com to net
    var newHostName = hostName.ToString().Substring(0, hostName.ToString().Length - 4) + ".net";

    // Creating new url
    :
    :
}
```

I have not tested it but it should work.